# Is it possible to pass associative arguments in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Current Jenkins setup deploys single version of different services, if they are selected via Boolean parameter option.

Say, there are four services in total - `A, B, C, D` and the version to be deployed will remain same(1.0), for all services. If only A is checked/enabled, script will deploy version `1.0` for service A and the same logic applies for other services.

[image]

[image]

Now the change being, each service can have its own version to be deployed when its selected. I'm not sure how to handle this in Jenkins.

Ex . If service_A is selected, it should have a placeholder or mapping to get its corresponding deployment version also and the same goes for other services too.

Is it possible via Jenkins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Non-Pipeline Solution with Active choice plugin.

You can get this done using the [Active Choice Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/). This supports HTML rendering. So in your case. First, let's get the Service name, and based on this we will render a text box.

First Add an `Active Choice Parameter`

[image]

For the Groovy script add the following content.

```
return ["Service01", "Service02"]
```

Next, add an `Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter` like below.

[image]

[image]

For the groovy part add the following content.

```
def htmlContent = "<table><tr>"

if(services.contains("Service01")){
 htmlContent = """
    ${htmlContent}
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label title=\"Service01\" class=\" \">Service 01 </label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type=\"text\" class=\" \" name=\"value\" value=\"version\"> </br>
    </td>
    </tr>
"""
}

if(services.contains("Service02")){
 htmlContent  = """
    ${htmlContent}
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label title=\"Service02\" class=\" \">Service 02 </label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type=\"text\" class=\" \" name=\"value\" value=\"version\"> </br>
    </td>
    </tr>
"""
}


htmlContent = "${htmlContent}</tr></table>"

return htmlContent
```

Make sure `Referenced parameters` are added. This needs to refer to the variable you used in the first parameter.

Now the pipeline execution will look like the below.

[image]

Note: Active Choice Parameter plugin does not support blue ocean UI.

## With A declarative Pipeline

If you are willing to take everything to a declarative pipeline you can do something like the below.

```
def INPUT_1 = ""
def INPUT_2 = ""

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
     stage("Get Inputs") {
                steps{
                    timeout(time: 300, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                    script {
                        // The Initial Choice
                        INPUT_1 = input message: 'Please select', ok: 'Next',
                                        parameters: [
                                        choice(name: 'SERVICE', choices: ['Service01','Service02'], description: 'Please select')]
                              
                        if(INPUT_1.equals("Service01")) {
                              INPUT_2 = input message: 'Please Select', ok: 'Next',
                                              parameters: [ choice(name: 'Version', choices: ['v01','v02'], description: 'Please select')] 
                        } else {
                              INPUT_2 = input message: 'Please Select', ok: 'Next',
                                        parameters: [
                                        choice(name: 'Version', choices: ["v1.1","v1.2","v1.3"], description: 'Select the file')]              
                        }

                        echo "INPUT 1 ::: ${INPUT_1}"
                        echo "INPUT 2 ::: ${INPUT_2}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    post {
        success {
            echo 'The process is successfully Completed....'
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in the following.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your time here :) Appreciate it, but unfortunately, I cant change the build flow or setup.

Comment: @ChelMS In that case you will have to use something like the Active Choice plugin. I updated my answer.